# writing a bash script to run in gpu

Tags: bash, gpu

I am writing a script to run a sequence of bash scripts and it would be idea to run the programs embedded in them on the GPU to speed this up.   I haven't found any obvious way to make this happen without appealing to python.  I am running this on Ubtuntu 18 and don't have access to a network to run a grid system and I haven't been able to successfully set up this to run in parallel either...it would be ideal to cut some time off if possible.

Ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more detail about what you're trying to do in order to get a good answer here. In general though, GPU's can only handle very specialized operations like matrix multiplications, not general bash scripts, so I don't think you will have much luck with this approach.

Comment: basically it is a series of scripts which pull out different parts of the neuroimaging package freesurfer and a variety of different programs which basically are doing huge number of matrix operations and minimization of cost functions etc etc

Comment: Do you want to execute pure bash (for instance `if`, `for`, `$(())`) on the GPU, or rather external programs (for instance `freesurfer`)? In both cases you are out of luck, but in the latter case even more so.

Comment: it is a series of bash scripts which call different parts of freesurfer interleaved with parts of other programs......i am looking for ways to speed up the programs run time when they are called....the programs have to run sequentially but i would like to speed each of them up running on a single computer

Comment: There would need to be some exploitable inefficiency which may not exist at the script level. Neuroimaging software might be fast already in areas such as threads and coroutines. The usual answer is to rent some cloud space.